# How do I parse a string like "-8y5d" to a Period object in joda time

Tags: jodatime

I want to parse strings like "8y5d" or "-6y144d" into a joda time period object. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Use the [PeriodFormatterBuilder](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatterBuilder.html):

```
    PeriodFormatter yearsAndMonths = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
        .printZeroRarelyFirst()
        .appendYears()
        .appendSuffix("y", "y")
        .printZeroRarelyLast()
        .appendDays()
        .appendSuffix("d", "d")
        .toFormatter();
    System.out.println(yearsAndMonths.parsePeriod("8y5d").toDurationFrom(new DateTime()).getStandardDays());
```